# Maxima: How to preserve prompt message to user (e.g. asksign()) when customizing output display?

Tags: maxima

I'm developing an interface to Maxima (from R), that changes the output display of maxima on startup via an init-file:

```
load("mactex-utilities")$
load("alt-display.mac")$
set_prompt('prefix, "prompt;>>")$
set_prompt('suffix, "<<prompt;")$
my_display(x):=(?princ("out;>>"), ?princ("(%o"), ?princ(linenum), ?princ(") "), tex(?caddr(x)), ?princ("<<out;"))$
set_alt_display(2, my_display)$
```

Now I'm trying to handle cases were Maxima prompts the user to declare assumptions about variables like in this example:

```
(%i1) L: sqrt(1 - 1/(R^2));
                                          1
(%o1)                            sqrt(1 - --)
                                           2
                                          R
(%i2) integrate(x, x, 0, L);
Is R positive or negative?

positive;
                                     2
                                    R  - 1
(%o2)                               ------
                                        2
                                     2 R
(%i3)
```

So the default display shows a prompt message "Is R positive or negative?". However, when I use the initialization file above, this message does not get printed. However, the console waits for the user input. So my question is, if there is a way, so I can include it in my customized output. Preferably, I think it should be possible to also wrap it in pre-/suffix strings for my interface to properly catch it, but I'm not too versed with maxima internals.

Just for the record, my interface's repo is https://www.github.com/rcst/rmaxima

Comment: I don't know much about the alt-display machinery, but anyway, I see that there is a global variable `alt_format_prompt` which appears to be able to define an alternative for the usual asksign questions, however, I don't have any experience using it. May I ask what documentation you are working with? I see there is `doc/implementation/external-interface.txt`, maybe you know about that already. I think this question may require more discussion; consider raising the issue on the Maxima mailing list. See: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss

Comment: The good news is that this problem must be solved one way or another by every user interface for Maxima, so it is a known problem with what is probably a conventional solution at this point. Sorry I can't be more helpful at the moment.

Comment: Thank you @RobertDodier! I wasn't aware of `doc/implementation/external-interface.txt` following it's examples on setting prompt variables, doesn't work with `alt_format_prompt`. I discovered it's a maxima variable and needs to be accessed as `$alt_format_prompt`. I read the documentation on sourceforge (https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_174.html). Could you point me to a specific project of an interface where this setting is exposed?

Comment: Well, on looking at it again, I think `alt_format_prompt` is not actually what you need to set the asksign prompt, so I apologize for the confusion. It looks to me like it will be necessary to resort to Lisp programming in order to achieve what you're trying -- see RETRIEVE in src/macsys.lisp. I *think* the issue is that RETRIEVE says output should go to `*standard-output*` (this is the argument T for FORMAT-PROMPT) and you need to specify a different output stream. Do you already have an output stream? Maybe you need to somehow ensure `*standard-output*` goes into that stream.

Comment: In Common Lisp there is a concept of synonym streams; maybe that's relevant here. In any event I think some discussion is needed -- maybe you can follow up to maxima-discuss which I linked above.

Comment: By the way, about an example of user interface which, so far as I know, has solved this problem, you can take a look at wxMaxima. From what I know, a way to contact the developers is via the wxMaxima issue tracker: https://github.com/wxMaxima-developers/wxmaxima/issues

Comment: From what I understand it should be fine when RETRIEVE directs the output to `*standard-output*`, because I'm reading and re-directing it on C++ level. So in maxima, I haven't defined any other output stream. Would you say, that's a better way to capture these user prompts? (BTW: I posted this question in maxima-discuss, no response yet)

Comment: About your message to maxima-discuss, I saw a response from Leo Butler: https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/mailman/message/37235457/ Perhaps it wasn't delivered to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This topic has been resolved on the maxima mailing list ([here](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/mailman/maxima-discuss/thread/861rcpecz2.fsf%40x201.butler.org/#msg37235457))

In essence this seems to be a bug in the `alt-display.lisp` code

Thanks to Leo Butler, here is a re-written version of the initialization script that in addition customizes user prompt messages that circumvents the problem.

```
(load("mactex-utilities"), load("alt-display.mac"));
(set_prompt('prefix, "prompt;>>",'suffix, "<<prompt;"),
my_display(x):=block([type], type:?caar(x),
if type=?mtext then printf(true,"~%TEXT;>>~%~a~%<<TEXT;~%",?cadr(x))
else if type=?mlabel then printf(true,"~%out;>>~%(~a) ~a~a~a~%<<out;~%",?cadr(x),"$$",tex1(?caddr(x)),"$$")
else block([alt_display1d:false, alt_display2d:false], displa(x))),
set_alt_display(2,my_display)) $
```

When using this to initialize maxima, the output for the above example is

```
prompt;>>(%i1) <<prompt;L: sqrt(1 - 1/(R^2));

out;>>
(%o1) $$\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{R^2}}$$
<<out;
prompt;>>(%i2) <<prompt;integrate(x, x, 0, L);
prompt;>>
TEXT;>>Is R positive or negative?<<TEXT;
<<prompt;
p;

out;>>
(%o2) $$\frac{R^2-1}{2\,R^2}$$
<<out;
prompt;>>(%i3) <<prompt;
```